# Simulate IR remote heater

Tags: arduino, infrared

I am trying to simulate the same IR code coming from my Heater remote control, but it seems like is not a standard code transmitting.
I have took a part the device and I discovered there is a CHIP BEC5104S which is an IR generator which has poorly documentation.

I am using Arduino to recreate the pulse with IRremote library which allow me to read the raw timing and play it back. The result is that with my DVR and TV everything works fine but as soon as I try to record my heater remote, it doesnt transmit correctly.

I tried to simulate the IR with a simple schematic like this https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/000/550/medium800/light_irremotetest.gif?1447976110 ( I double checked with a phone camera that was transmitting ) but still didnt work.

I was thinking that my IR led wasnt the right specs, then I replace on my remote and it did work.
[image]

I have hooked it up to the Oscilloscope to understand if the signal was 38khz and it is.

I am not sure how to translate the timing from my oscilloscope as it seems to have ON and OFF timing the same.

How can I make sure I can match the 6 codes of my remote? Should I just hook it up to my arduino with an interrupt and trying to record it?

Comment: Is the ON OFF timing you mention the 38kHz signal? in that case, zoom out on your scope and look at the blocks of 38kHz waves and 'silence'. Normally that is the signal you need to replicate.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to look into that ON and OFF signal but it seems to be the same for the 15 jumps, like same timing which is odd as I have 6 different buttons and the signal is always the same. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the scope.

Comment: Can you add photos/screenshots of the scope?